# Is it possible to use mongodb with sqlalchemy?

Tags: mongodb, sqlalchemy

I can't find any information about connecting to mongodb in the [documents of sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) and google search.

Is it possible to use mongodb with sqlalchemy? Thanks.

Comment: No you can't use MongoDB with sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

as per sql alchem desc you cannot use it:

> SQLAlchemy considers the database to be a relational algebra engine,
>   not just a collection of tables. Rows can be selected from not only
>   tables but also joins and other select statements; any of these units
>   can be composed into a larger structure. SQLAlchemy's expression
>   language builds on this concept from its core.
>
> SQLAlchemy is most famous for its object-relational mapper (ORM), an
>   optional component that provides the data mapper pattern, where
>   classes can be mapped to the database in open ended, multiple ways -
>   allowing the object model and database schema to develop in a cleanly
>   decoupled way from the beginning.
>
> The main goal of SQLAlchemy is to change the way you think about
>   databases and SQL!

Answer (score 5):

You may use MongoAlchemy instead.