# Flask error: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, sqlalchemy

I am basically trying to integrate my mlab database with my flask app and I keep getting the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mongodb
```

I tested the mlab database already using the mongo shell and it worked fine but some reason the app has a problem acessing it

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

#tells srl alchemy how to connect to our database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxxx@ds111103.mlab.com:11103/namebase'

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"]= False


db=SQLAlchemy(app)
class Comment(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(20))
    column=db.Column(db.String(200))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/sign')
def sign():
    return render_template('sign.html')

@app.route("/process",methods=["POST"])
def process():
    name=request.form["name"]
    comment=request.form['comment']
    return render_template("index.html",
                        name=name,comment=comment
                        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: MongoDB is not an included [SQLAlchemy dialect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/). I would suggest taking a look at [MongoEngine (GitHub)](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine) or [flask-mongoengine (GitHub)](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use MongoDB with SQLAlchemy. This is because SQLAlchemy considers the database to be a relational algebra engine. This means that your database must be a relational database with rows and columns such as MySQL. Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387273/is-it-possible-to-use-mongodb-with-sqlalchemy).

MongoDB on the other hand is a NoSQL database which is a JSON-based model. To connect to a MongoDB database in Flask, a relatively new library is available called [Flask-MongoAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387273/is-it-possible-to-use-mongodb-with-sqlalchemy). The usage is similar to Flask-SQLAlchemy. I hope this helps.